# Setting accessibility hint to UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, accessibility, uinavigationitem, voiceover

I would like the voiceover to read out a custom message after the title for the view is read out. To achieve this, I have set the accessibility hint for the navigation item.

```
self.navigationItem.accessibilityHint= @"Custom message.";
```

However the voiceover does not read out the hint for a UINavigationItem. It only reads out the title and stops at that. 
Appending text to accessibility label is an option, I believe is a workaround if this doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

What I'm trying to achieve is to instruct the user to handover the device to another user when a particular screen is shown. I want the instruction to be read out after the title is read out.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the hint on the specific `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: I want the voice over to read the navigation title first and then the hint. Setting it on UIBarButtonItem would read the title of bar button item and then read out the hint.

Comment: Right. But you need to set the hint on the actual bar button item. Then when the user taps the bar button item, the button's title will be read, then the hint.

Comment: Edited my question to give a better context as to why I need the hint on title and not on the bar button item.

Comment: Oh, you want the view controller's title to have the hint. That I don't know how to do without setting an explicit `titleView` for the navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

The accessibility hint is intended for describing **how to interact** with a particular interface element on screen. `UINavigationItem`s are typically not interactive, hence the accessibility hint is the wrong place to put your custom message. In turn, this is also why it is not being read out.

Would putting your custom message in the navigation item's accessibility label not achieve the same effect? You could add a hyphen to create a short pause:

```
NSString *accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%1$@ - Custom message."), self.navigationItem.title];
self.navigationItem.accessibilityLabel = accessibilityLabel;
```